# Touch is like 20px off on an iPad after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad

I've googled all over and can't find any fixes for this.

For some reason on my site, when you scroll down even 1px, then the menu can be trigged from about 20px below it. Everything else still needs to be clicked directly, but after scrolling the menu doesn't know where it is.

Any ideas? Can anyone point me in the right direction for this type of issue?

Guhh iPads

Comment: Is this on Safari, Chrome, etc.?

Comment: Safari and Edge Inspect. The website is http://fastgateopeners.com and for the life of me I can't figure out why touch is offset after scrolling. We don't have a Mac where I work so I'm just trying to debug it with the awful Edge Inspect and then guessing at my changes.